# Can I make Java Custom rules analyze a Android Project on SonarQube?

Tags: java, android, sonarqube, rules

I'm creating some rules to SonarQube where it will analyze a Android Project and raise some Security vulnerabilityes points on code.

I've already created a custom rule by [Sonar Tutorial](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) to create my own rules following the same structure, but I had some complications. For instance, when I tryed to run the test classes, I've found some problems to [identify Android Classes and validate my rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766635/how-to-use-android-classes-on-a-sonarqube-custom-rule), and after some research, I solved the problem, but seems like when I put my plugin on SonarQube and run it, the problem remains with the tool not identifying Android Classes (I coudn't comprove this because coudn't find a way to debug the web tool and see why the Rule is not checking).

By this, I need to know if I'm really doing this of the right way. Analyze with custom rules a Android Project directly by SonarQube can be done just following the Sonar Tutorial? Do I need of custom configurations inside my template or any other step to do it?

If beyond the answer or the instruction, someone could provide some documentation to help me, I would be deeply grateful.

Since now, thanks for your attention!